# Low power way to extend a short pulse

Tags: signal, timer, low-power

How would I extend a short active high digital pulse (around 1 us) to about a couple of ms with few uA of current consumption? The exact time of extension isn't important. I am working in the 3.3V voltage range and I can get either a push-pull or open-drain output for the short pulse. Driving strength of the output of pulse can be around 10 mA.

Update: I followed suggestion of @Uwe and it worked.

Comment: a low-power microcontroller can do that. A CMOS 555 variant can do that. Heck, a MOSFET, an R and a C can do that.

Comment: also, your requirement makes no sense: microampere of current consumption can never source 10 mA...

Comment: @MarcusMüller, If the microamps is an average, and the milliamps is a peak current, then it depends on the duty cycle whether you can or can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look for a monostable multivibrator like this https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G123

It may operate with 3.3 V and Icc 20 µA. With C = 100 nF and R = 10 kOhm you get a 1 ms pulse, 1µF and 100 kOhm 100 ms.

Answer (score 1):

You may have more current available than you think: the pulse extender can probably be powered by the energy of the pulse itself.

My approach would be to pass the leading edge of the pulse, and then turn off a pass gate some 0.5us later. That way the pulse has done the job of charging the load circuit. You then disconnect the source and connect a monostable to hold the output high. Eventually the monostable’s output goes low, the gate can be re-enabled, and the circuit can turn off until the next pulse arrives.

Since CMOS can be pretty leaky when hot, to really turn it off you can use a bipolar transistor that can consume fraction of a micro amp to stay unsaturated so it will turn on faster. It’s a tight squeeze energy-budget-wise, but the power consumption by the circuit will be mostly determined by the load, and the circuit should consume something like 100nA when off and hot, and maybe 10uA when active at the very most. It takes more power to drive 10mA using bipolars than room temp CMOS logic, so in the active state the circuit should be CMOS, but in idle state it can be bipolar.

For low saturated voltage drop, use the NPN or PNP with collector an emitter switched: this doubles the current consumption when *on*, but also allows you to drive the output very close to the rails.